# Unable to un-highlight selection in 2 different paragraphs using Rangy library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rangy

JSfiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/9jp346r4/20/

I am trying to create functionality that allows user to highlight the selected text upon pressing a button, and unhighlight the highlighted text upon right-clicking.

I've gotten it mostly working using the rangy library except there's one scenario that doesn't work and I'm not sure how to solve it.

When I highlight text that is in 2 different paragraphs, it highlights it successfully.

The issue arises when I would like to come back later and un-highlight both the paragraphs.

The expected behaviour is: I right-click any highlighted text regardless of if it is selected or not and it will un-highlight all nearby highlighted text even if it's separated by a paragraph tag or strong tag.

The current behaviour is: It only unhighlights the text in the paragraph I clicked.

To re-produce: 
1) Select text that overlaps both the first and second paragraph and press the "Press" button.

2) Un-select the selected text by clicking somewhere else on the screen.

3) Right-click any of the highlighted text. Notice only one of the paragraphs gets un-highlighted.

If something is unclear, feel free to ask questions. Would appreciate the help.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<p>
Paragraph 1
</p>
<p>
Paragraph 2
</p>
</div>
<div id="divId">
   <input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Press" onclick = "javascript:toggleItalicYellowBg()"/>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function coverAll() {
  var ranges = [];
  for(var i=0; i<window.getSelection().rangeCount; i++) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(i);
    while(range.startContainer.nodeType == 3
          || range.startContainer.childNodes.length == 1)
      range.setStartBefore(range.startContainer);
    while(range.endContainer.nodeType == 3
          || range.endContainer.childNodes.length == 1)
      range.setEndAfter(range.endContainer);
    ranges.push(range);
  }
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  for(var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
    window.getSelection().addRange(ranges[i]);
  }
  return true;
}

function getSelectedText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    return document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return '';
}

var italicYellowBgApplier;

function toggleItalicYellowBg() {
  italicYellowBgApplier.toggleSelection();
}

window.onload = function() {
  $(document).on("contextmenu", ".italicYellowBg", function(e){
    if(coverAll()) {
      italicYellowBgApplier.undoToSelection();
      return false;
    }
  });
  rangy.init();


  // Enable buttons
  var classApplierModule = rangy.modules.ClassApplier;

  // Next line is pure paranoia: it will only return false if the browser has no support for ranges,
  // selections or TextRanges. Even IE 5 would pass this test.
  if (rangy.supported && classApplierModule && classApplierModule.supported) {

    italicYellowBgApplier = rangy.createClassApplier("italicYellowBg",       {
      tagNames: ["span", "a", "b", "img"]
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I think it does, otherwise it wouldn't un-highlight everything, even though nothing was selected. Right?

Comment: sorry, not selection. your range... I'd suggest you putting a `debugger;` in the line above `window.getSelection().addRange(ranges[i]);` and see that

Comment: Ah... yeah, well that piece of code hasn't been coded to do what I want it to. I'm unsure how to go about dealing with text that ends up separated by other tags like <p> tags

Comment: Actually, the problem seems to be in the way you're getting the range, maybe would work if you check if the first character of the next item is selected you would include it in the `endContainer`

Answer (score 0):

I guess to easy solve this problem, in memory keep an array of user highlights, one item of that array is not a single highlight item, but a further "selection of selected items during the highlight", when somebody would right click on a single segment of highlight, in-memory find from array all associated highlights and unhighlight the related segments by yourself.